# Overlapping results on mysql query when using limit/offset

Tags: mysql, database, pagination, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I'm new to databases, and im not sure why this isnt working.

My objective is to get all the users in a database except the first one. I would also like this to be sortable, so it contains ORDER BY.

I finally got pagination to work, but the query is returning overlapping results on different pages

QUERY:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `users` as `User`  WHERE '1'='1' AND `User`.`id` > '1'  ORDER BY User.active ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

i get these back (here is their IDs in the order i got)
32,18,19,16,15,14,13,12,11,2

Now with the LIMIT part set to 10,100, i get these back
32,20,19,2,11,12,13,14,15,15

I'm not sure why i get overlapping results. Help?

Thanks :)

Comment: Ask me if any query!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

SELECT * FROM users as User WHERE '1'='1' AND User.id > 1 ORDER BY User.id ASC LIMIT 0,10

OR TRY something simple:

SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id > 1 LIMIT 0,10

Comment: Thanks Jain, the first query does in fact stops the overlapping of results. How do i go by ordering by other fields in the table?

I guess i have to find a way to order by first then take the limit of that?

Comment: @above!! Yes order by is always works before limit applied. And order by can be set of any of your columns value.

Comment: Thanks. So i combined two simpler queries and it seems to be working SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT * FROM `users` as `User`  WHERE '1'='1' AND `User`.`id` > '1'  ORDER BY User.active ASC
) AS Outter LIMIT 0, 10